# A row in csv file is not deleted on gitlab when run through jenkins

Tags: jenkins, gitlab

I am running my scripts on jenkins through gitlab integration. I have a csv file in gitlab which have account numbers in each row. Once the script is run, it should read the first account number from the csv file and it should delete it. So if we run the script again, script should read next account number. But in my case, account number used in the 1st script is not getting deleted from gitlab.

Above scenario is working perfectly fine when I run in my local in eclipse. Please let me know why csv file is not getting updated in gitlab.

Your help is really appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just to be sure: do you commit and push the changes to gitlab within the script?

Comment: No. In the script we just update the csv file. We don't commit or push to git from the script level. When the run is started, project is imported to remote machine and it executes the scripts there. We are doing mvn clean install every time. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: If you want the file to be changed in gitlab you have to commit and push it.